# How do I extract the property name and value being passed into an Expression<Func<T,bool>>?

Tags: c#, lambda

Let's assume I have a method like this:

```
public static List<T> Get<T>(this SomeObject<T>, Expressions<Func<T,bool>> e){

//get the property name and value they want to check is true / false
...

}

TheObject().Get(x => x.PropertyName == "SomeValue");
```

How do I get "PropertyName" and "SomeValue" when I pass it into the Get extension method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is what you're after

```
BinaryExpression expression = ((BinaryExpression)e.Body);
string name = ((MemberExpression)expression.Left).Member.Name;
Expression value = expression.Right;


Console.WriteLine(name);
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Output:

```
PropertyName
SomeValue
```

Error checking is left as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: Are there any resources you know of on extracting multiple parameters and operators: (c => c.FirstName.Contains("A") && c.Address.Place == "Beach" || c.Address.Place == "Mountains"). I looked at the tree and it blew my mind.

Comment: No sorry, I just sort of experimented and looked at the expression tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var expressionBody= e.Body.ToString();
```

will return a string like the below:

```
//"(x.PropertyName == \"SomeValue\")"
```

there are also more accurate way to do it (for example compiling it) but the performance of compiling the expression are really bad for what you are asking

Comment: he said "How do I get "PropertyName" and "SomeValue" .

with my solution he can get this result without compiling the expression.Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you can always get the desired result without compiling the expression. Actually, compiling it won't get the desired result. What I meant before was that you don't know why they need this, so you can't tell if the performance will be *really bad* or *enough*.

Comment: Ok probably I did't explain myself properly

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Web.Mvc` namespace might be able to help you re-rolling this. Take a look at [`ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TParameter, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428393.aspx)